How to return a unique_ptr reference to a const type
I'd like a member function to return a unique_ptr reference to a const type, just like in raw pointers.
Here is what I mean:
class Foo {
   private:
      int _number;

   public:
      [[nodiscard]] explicit Foo(int number) : _number(number) {}
      [[nodiscard]] int number() const { return _number; }
      void set_number(int number) { _number = number; }
};

class ManageFoo {
   private:
      std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr;

   public:
      explicit ManageFoo(std::unique_ptr<Foo> &&foo_ptr) : foo_ptr(std::move(foo_ptr)) {};

      void set_number(const int &number) {
         foo_ptr->set_number(number);
         // And perform something else...
      }

      const Foo *getFoo() { return foo_ptr.get(); }
};

I want the user of ManageFoo to change the state of Foo only through ManageFoo's set_number. That's why I want getFoo to return a pointer to const Foo. I want the user to access only a read-only version of Foo. In order to avoid using foo_ptr.get() is it possible to write a getFoo returning std::unique_ptr<const Foo>& ?

const Foo *getFoo() const { return foo_ptr.get(); } is a perfect getter. What advantage of returning std::unique_ptr<const Foo>& do you expect?

Your request seems like a mistake.  It is only appropriate to return std::unique_ptr when you are transferring ownership.  In your case, it sounds like ManageFoo continues to be the owner.  If ManageFoo::foo_ptr remains valid, it must be the only unique_ptr in existence (that's what unique means)

However, I might consider providing const Foo* operator->() const, and const Foo& operator*() const either replacing getFoo() or in addition.

Please also note that if you did succeed in having unique_ptr<const Foo>& getFoo(), the caller could do mfoo.getFoo().reset(new Foo(42)), replacing the whole Foo object our from under the ManageFoo.  Pointer-to-const is not the same as a const pointer, and that remains true for smart pointers.

My concern is that if I expose a raw pointer, a user may try to delete it somewhere else. Voigt's last observation is interesting: my request should be  "const unique_ptr& getFoo()" !!

I used to return unique_ptr references because I though they added clarity. After talking with other programmers using my code I was convinced that it added little but pain.  Now I return raw pointers when ownership is not being transferred and trust my co-workers to not shoot themselves in the foot with the the raw pointer.

In modern C++ no one should be deleting raw pointers. (unless you are writing your own smart pointer).

a user may try to delete it somewhere else - such user would not even stop at delete foo.get().

Since it is possible to return a "const Foo*" from a "Foo*", wouldn't it be nice to have this also in unique_pointers? What do you think?

You're talking about the const-propagation property that none of the standard smart pointers currently have. Yes, that property might be desirable, but it's orthogonal to the fact that you shouldn't pass or return unique_ptr except to deliberately transfer ownership.

"My concern is that if I expose a raw pointer, a user may try to delete it somewhere else." -- If you expose the object, a user may try to delete it somewhere else. It doesn't matter if you return a smart pointer, a raw pointer, or a reference; if the user can access the object directly, the address is available and can be given to delete. That's not your problem. C++ is not a safe language for those determined to break conventions.


void set_number(const int &number) {
  foo_ptr->set_number(number);
  // And perform something else...
}


foo_ptr never seems to get null. Then it can be like below to resolve your concerns in the comments.
const Foo& getFoo() const { return *foo_ptr; }

